# Laravel 5: How to create a router model binding on multiple parameters

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

So far I know how to create a router model binding on single parameters like so:

```
// RouteServiceProvider.php
$router->model('subject_slug', 'App\Subject', function($slug) {
     return Subject::where('slug', $slug)->firstOrFail();
});
```

The above can then be used like this:

```
// routes.php
Route::get('/{subject_slug}', 'MenuController@showSubject');
```

And in the controller:

```
public function showSubject(Subject $subject) {
   ....
}
```

But sometimes I need to specify multiple parameters in order to get the right model.

For example consider the following route:

```
Route::get('/{subject_slug}/{topic_slug}/', 'MenuController@showTopic');
```

and the corresponding controller:

```
public function showTopic(Subject $subject, Topic $topic) {
   ....
}
```

However to get the correct model for `Topic` I need to know the `Subject`. For example:

```
// !!! Invalid laravel code !!!
$router->model('topic_slug', 'App\Topic, function($subject_slug, $topic_slug) {
     // ERROR: $subject_slug is obviously not defined!
     return Topic::where([
        'subject_slug' => $subject_slug,
        'slug' => $topic_slug,
     ])->firstOrFail();
});
```

How can I make a router model binding for `Topic` bearing in mind I need to know the `Subject` parameter before it in order to fetch the correct `Topic`.

Is there an alternative better way of doing this?

**UPDATE**

Currently my `showTopic` method in my controller is like this:

```
public function showTopic(Subject $subject, $topic_slug) {
   $topic = Topic::where([
               'subject_slug' => $subject_slug,
               'slug' => $topic_slug,
            ])->firstOrFail();
   // ...
}
```

and I have no router model binding for `topic_slug`.
This works as expected, but I would like to take advantage of router model bindings!

Comment: I suspect there is no way of doing this, since what you're trying to do is, in effect, bind two models (`Subject` and `Topic`) to one route. You will probably have to fall back to good old route binding without the model binding to accomplish this.

Comment: Yeah that what i used. Didn't even know about `bind`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the way I was doing it was a bit flawed. I was unnessarily using model bindings when instead it would be better to have used a normal binding like so:

```
$router->bind('topic_slug', function($slug, Route $route) {
     $subject = $route->parameter('subject_slug');
     return Topic::where([
        'subject_slug' => $subject->slug,
        'slug' => $slug,
     ])->firstOrFail();
});
```

Also I was using model bindings completely wrong before as the 3rd function should be the "not found behaviour" (not for additional logic)!